# Hanging on connection to display

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

from Xlib.display import Display
import os

def main():
        disp = Display() # connect to display
        while True:
                print("1")
                event = disp.next_event()
                print("2")
                if event.type == Xlib.protocol.event.KeyPress:
                        print("keypress!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

This code outputs `1` but does not output `2`. It seems to be hanging on the display connection. Why might that be? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method next_event() is a blocking method, see the [documentation](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/python-xlib_11.html):

> Return the next event in the event queue. If the event queue is empty,
>   block until an event is read from the network, and return that one.

If it is blocked it is because no event has yet arrived.